# Dart/Flutter - ¿Como ejecutar un metodo tras otro?

Tags: flutter, dart

En Python nosotros podemos hacer esto: `respuesta = objeto.metodo1().metodo2()`

Sin embargo, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo en Flutter?

Quiero algo como esto en Dart/Flutter:

```
    class MiClase{
         void metodo1(){}
         String metodo2() => 'Hola Mundo';
    }

   main(){
        MiClase _miClase = MiClase();
        String resultado = _miClase.metodo1().metodo2();
        print(resultado);
   }
```

EDITADO: Ya lo resolví, dejaré la solución.

```
class MiClase(){
     MiClase metodo1() => this;
     String metodo2() => 'Hola Mundo';
}

main(){
    MiClase _miClase = MiClase();
    String resultado = _miClase.metodo1().metodo2();
    print(resultado);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si ya lo resolviste, agrégala tu solución **como respuesta** (siguiendo las guías de [answer]), y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según ["AVOID returning this from methods just to enable a fluent interface."](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-returning-this-from-methods-just-to-enable-a-fluent-interface) la forma adecuada de usar métodos encadenados no pasa por retornar el objeto sino usar la notación `..`. Por ejemplo:

```
class CalculadoraSimple {
  
  int _valor = 0;
  
  CalculadoraSimple(int valor) { _valor = valor; }
  suma(int newvalue) { _valor = _valor + newvalue; }
  resta(int newvalue) { _valor = _valor - newvalue; }
  void ver() { print("El valor hasta el momento es: $_valor"); }
}

main(){
 
  CalculadoraSimple(10)
             ..suma(5)
             ..resta(2)
             ..ver()
             ..suma(100)
             ..ver();
}
```